# Single Instance of HttpClient vs Multiples Instances with ClientCredentias?

Tags: c#, httpclient, x509certificate, credentials, socketexception

I'm using HttpClient to make request to a Soap Api.
I saw that is recommended to use a single instance of HttpClient instead once for each request to avoid SocketException.

In my Desktop app, I need to make multiples requests, each one with differents credentials. I'm doing it like the sample code:

```
WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

using(var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler))
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://nfe-homologacao.svrs.rs.gov.br/ws/nfeinutilizacao/nfeinutilizacao4.asmx", httpContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to avoid creates an instance of HttpClient for each request. I saw that correct way is use static instance like this:

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

But with static instance, I can't set credentials with WebRequestHandler. Please note that credentials change in each request.

What is the better way to perform all requests, avoiding SocketException and using differents credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally per request credentials should be set for each request created:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer");
await client.SendAsync(request);
```

You can also do this in your own web request handler:

```
class SetCredentialsWebRequestHandler : WebRequestHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

client = new HttpClient(new SetCredentialsWebRequestHandler());
await client.PostAsync(url);
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments, I learned the question requires using certificate authentication. So in this case, multiple instances (one per certificate) would be a better option.

There will be not point to reuse the same connection for different client certificate.

Check out this named `HttpClient`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#named-clients

`HttpClient` could be named as per the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for reply! In my case, I use X509Certificate2 instead Bearer Token. Should this example work too?

Comment: No. Sorry I thought the client cert is generic and you're using request level authorization. If using certificate, you need `HttpClient` **per certificate**. Certificate auth happens during SSH/TLS handshake which is during establishing the connection. The whole point of reusing `HttpClient` is to reuse the underlying connection.

Comment: Then I could create a list of HttpClient and reuse clients that have the same certificates. Would that be a good approach?

Comment: I'd recommend `IHttpClientFactory` and named `HttpClient`. You could name `HttpClient` as per the certificate. Check out the link in my updated answer.

Comment: But if you don't have dependency injection stuff in your app, then yes, a list / dictionary should also do. Just need to make sure that you dispose them *eventually*.

Comment: Thanks! I am using .net framework 4.5 and I think `IHttpClientFactory` is only for .net core...

Comment: Yes. It's from nuget package targeting .net standard 2.0, which can't be used in .net 4.5 (.net standard 1.1) unfortunately.

Comment: So the best alternative is List/Dictionary with dispose, correct?

Comment: Yes. List / dictionary / your own manager class. Long as you could dispose them at the end when no longer needed. It is also fine if they have same lifetime as your app. It is just the TCP connections will remain half-open for a while before they can close.